# Access uploaded file from wwwroot folder

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

i had selected image/file from input tag and then save it in wwwroot folder i want to show that selected file in view.

```
 <table>

        <tr>
            <th>File Name</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (FileModel file in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@file.FileName</td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadFile", new { fileName = file.FileName })</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="contactForm1">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-icon fs-xl mr-1" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Attach files" data-placement="top">

            <div>
                <input type="file" id="choose-file" name="formFile" />

                <label for="choose-file"> <i class="fal fa-paperclip color-fusion-300"></i></label>

            </div>
        </a>
        <button class="btn btn-info shadow-0 ml-auto " id="postimg">Post</button>
    </form>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var frm = $('#contactForm1');

        frm.submit(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                data: new FormData(this),
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('Thank God it worked!');
                }
            }
            );
        });
```

its my view

```
 public IActionResult Index(IFormFile formFile)
        {
            
            
            try
            {
                

                    string fileName = formFile.FileName;
                fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
                string uploadpath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\Files", fileName);
                var stream = new FileStream(uploadpath, FileMode.Create);
                formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                ViewBag.Message = "File uploaded successfully.";
            }
            catch
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Error while uploading the files.";
            }
            //Fetch all files in the Folder (Directory).
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(this.Environment.WebRootPath, "Files/"));
          

            //Copy File names to Model collection.
            List<FileModel> files = new List<FileModel>();
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                files.Add(new FileModel { FileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath) });
            }

            

            return View(files);
        }
```

controller data its all working fine but it show all file from root folder i just want to get only single file which i just selected.
like when the user select and image and post its uploaded in wwwroot folder now it should be uploaded on view

Comment: What's your `FileModel` looks like? You fetch all files in the Folder, and return View(files);, so it show all file from root folder .

Comment: @QingGuo yes i know that is my question it is showing all file what should i do it only display last uploaded file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> only display last uploaded file
>
> i want the image after post

Below is a demo about display  something about last uploaded file, you can refer to it.

1.Chane your code like below:

```
        try
        {
            string fileName = formFile.FileName;
            fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
            string uploadpath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\Files", fileName);
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(uploadpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))        
           {
                formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);    
                ViewBag.Message = "File uploaded successfully.";
            }
         }
         catch
        {
                ViewBag.Message = "Error while uploading the files.";
        }
                   
            string filePath = @"copy your Files/ path here " + formFile.FileName;
            byte[] byteData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
            string imreBase64Data = Convert.ToBase64String(byteData);
            string imgDataURL = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", imreBase64Data);
            return Json(new { fileName = formFile.FileName, fileSize = formFile.Length, imgDataURL = imgDataURL });
```

2.add  below in your view:

```
        File Name: <strong><span id="fileNameSpan"></span></strong>
        <br />
        File Size: <strong><span id="fileSizeSpan"></span></strong>
        <img id="imgDesign" src="" alt="design" />
```

3.make some change to your success function:

```
success: function (data) {
                    console.log('Thank God it worked!');
                     $("#fileNameSpan").html(data.fileName);
                     $("#fileSizeSpan").html(data.fileSize);
                     $("#imgDesign").attr("src", data.imgDataURL );
                }
```

result:

[image]

Comment: yes you are great thanks alot, but i more this as its showing name and size like this if i want to show image too then what i had to do .

Comment: @jiya Where do you want to show image? Do you want to show the  image without page refresh? If that, I think you should return something that the browser can understand. If you want to use refresh the page , you need to use another action and create another view to display the image.

Comment: @Ging Guo i want to show the image on page without refresh. user can select image and upload on page. like social media post.

Comment: its just a preview i want the image after post

Comment: @jiya  Ok, get the image after post. Please see my update answer.